# How to sum differents String from Snapshot in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have 4 variable which collect data from textformfield
these are are number and I need to sum them and place in a widget in flutter
for example I have:

```
static String test1;
  static String test2;
  static String test3 ;
  static String test4;
```

all these string are pushed to cloud firestore then each of this return value into the widget with:

```
${data['test1']}
${data['test2']}
${data['test3']}
${data['test4']}
```

but I need to sum all of them to have in one widget the sum of all these variable.

```
${data['test1']} + ${data['test2']} + ${data['test3']} + ${data['test4']}
```

how I can achieve that?

Comment: You have to convert them to `int` first before sum all up.

Comment: I think you're going to have to edit the question to show more code, and be clear where you are stuck, or what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@John Joe is right. You have to convert them to int. To explain in an example:

```
    // I assume your data sth like this. 
    data['test1'] = "1";
    data['test2'] = "9";
    data['test3'] = "2";
    data['test4'] = "3";
```

This process will give a result:

```
    ${data['test1']} + ${data['test2']} + ${data['test3']} + ${data['test4']} = "1923";
```

If you want to sum their mathematical values, you need to do this:

```
     int.parse(data['test1']) + int.parse(data['test2']) + int.parse(data['test3']) + int.parse(data['test4']) = 15;
```

Or, if they are double, you can use double.parse("value") method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// if values are integers use int

"${data.values.map((value)=>int.parse(value)).reduce((x,y)=>x+y)}";

// else if double

"${data.values.map((value)=>double.parse(value)).reduce((x,y)=>x+y)}";

// else

"${data.values.map((value)=>num.parse(value)).reduce((x,y)=>x+y)}";
```